# Reorder Dictionary on a part of an object

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how to sort an dictionary which looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, ParseObject> dict = new Dictionary<string, ParseObject>();
```

The ParseObject has some fields in it:

**objectId, name, date**

Which i can get like this:
dict.Get("date")

The data inside date looks like this: **20141028201007**

Now, I want to reorder/sort the dictionary on the date field either ascending or descending but don't know how to do this?

I have looked at this:

```
// Example dictionary.
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(5);
    dictionary.Add("cat", 1);
    dictionary.Add("dog", 0);
    dictionary.Add("mouse", 5);
    dictionary.Add("eel", 3);
    dictionary.Add("programmer", 2);

    // Order by values.
    // ... Use LINQ to specify sorting by value.
    var items = from pair in dictionary
            orderby pair.Value ascending
            select pair;

    // Display results.
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    // Reverse sort.
    // ... Can be looped over in the same way as above.
    items = from pair in dictionary
        orderby pair.Value descending
        select pair;
```

But this is not based on an object...

Hope someone can help or guide me in the right direction and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(5);
dictionary.Add("cat", 1);
dictionary.Add("dog", 0);
dictionary.Add("mouse", 5);
dictionary.Add("eel", 3);
dictionary.Add("programmer", 2);

var orderedPairs = dictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value);

foreach (var pair in orderedPairs)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Basically, you get an ordered `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`.

With your more complex object that would be:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, ParseObject> { ... };
var orderedPairs = dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Date);
```

Comment: What is the { ... } at the end? And how do i determin if it should be asc or desc?

Comment: The `{ ... }` is just initialization code that I skipped (because it's not so useful to sort an empty dictionary after all). If you want descending order, replace `.OrderBy` with `.OrderByDescending`

Comment: Super, but I tried this: var orderedPairs = dict.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value.Get("date")); - but I get this error: The type arguments for method `Parse.ParseObject.Get<T>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. - Not sure what to do?

Comment: I don't know what's theis `Get` function you're using, but you may try this, as a guess: `pair.Value.Get<DateTime>("date")`

Comment: Ah yeah, offcourse. Almost there... When trying this afterwards: foreach (ParseObject myobject in orderedPairs){
 Debug.Log ("Date: "+myobject.Get("date"));
}
I get this error: Cannot convert type `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,Parse.ParseObject>' to `Parse.ParseObject' - Why, I do not understand?!

Comment: `myobject` is a pair, you can use `myobject.Value.Get("date")`, or you can just add a select: `.OrderBy(...).Select(pair => pair.Value)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63897/discussion-between-mansa-and-lucas-trzesniewski).